# How to use Ionic, Capacitor, and Angular to track a user's location in the background after an app is closed?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, mapbox, capacitor

I am trying to develop a mobile app using Ionic, Capacitor, and Angular. I want to implement a feature that allows me to track a user's location in the background even after the app is closed.

I have tried using packages like https://github.com/capacitor-community/background-geolocation, but I was not successful.

Answer (score 0):

There's a great plugin for this that works: [capacitor-background-geolocation](https://github.com/transistorsoft/capacitor-background-geolocation)